# Flutter Image upload with http and multipart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

I am trying to upload user information (`imagePath`, `firstName`, `lastName`) to a server with the help of a http request.

```
Future<UserModel> userSignUp({
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    File imagePath,
  }) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "FNAME": firstName,
      "LNAME": lastName,
      "image": imagePath
    };
    var response = await _helper.post(
      Services.userSignUp,
      isSecure: false,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: json.encode(data),
    );
    return UserModel.fromJson(response);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a `MultipartRequest`, which is usually what's needed when uploading images or files to a server.

I'm assuming you're using the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http), so I think that you can find an example on how to perform this kind of request [here in the MultipartRequest documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html).